# How to set expiration time to parameter in ParameterStore aws .NET C#?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-parameter-store

I'm trying to store value in parameter store and to define TTL (Time To Live) for this value using C#, .NET with `PutParameterRequest`.
How should I do it ?

This is how I'm saving the parameter for now with no expiration date:

```
var parametersStoreRequest = new PutParameterRequest() 
{
  Name = "Miao",
  Value = "MiaoChech",
  Type = ParameterType.String,
}

try {
  var parametersStoreResponse = await parameterStoreClient.PutParameterAsync(parametersStoreRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !
Thank you @Arpit Jain for your answer :)

this is the correct format for PutParameterRequest in .net c#

```
var parameterStoreClient = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
            var currentTTL = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z");
            var parametersStoreRequest = new PutParameterRequest()
            {
                Name = "Miao",
                Value = "MiaoChech",
                Type = ParameterType.String,
                Policies= "[{'Type':'Expiration','Version':'1.0','Attributes':{'Timestamp':'"+currentTTL+"'}}]"
            };
            try
            {
                var parametersStoreResponse = await parameterStoreClient.PutParameterAsync(parametersStoreRequest);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Parameter policies to assign specific criteria to a parameter such as an *expiration date* or *time to live*. Parameter Store allows the following types of policies: `Expiration`, `ExpirationNotification`, and `NoChangeNotification`.

The following example shows the request syntax for a PutParameter API request that assigns `Expiration` to a new `SecureString` parameter named `Password`.

```
{
    "Name": "Password",
    "Description": "Parameter with policies",
    "Value": "P@ssW*rd21",
    "Type": "SecureString",
    "Overwrite": "True",
    "Policies": [
        {
            "Type": "Expiration",
            "Version": "1.0",
            "Attributes": {
                "Timestamp": "2018-12-02T21:34:33.000Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So you need to pass the `Policies` values as a string with One or more policies to apply to a parameter in `PutParameterRequest`.

```
"[{policies-enclosed-in-brackets-and-curly-braces}]"
```

I am not familiar with the .Net but I hope this will help you to implement your requirement.

**Note:** The `Expiration` policy deletes the parameter. You can specify a specific date and time by using either the `ISO_INSTANT` format or the `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` format.
The above example uses the `ISO_INSTANT` format. You can also specify a date and time by using the `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` format. Here is an example: `2019-11-01T22:13:48.87+10:30:00`.

Reference: [PutParameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_PutParameter.html#API_PutParameter_RequestSyntax)

Comment: Thank you!! but actually I meant to the format of the PutParameterRequest in .net

already solved it :)